# Perforce – Reconcile offline work detects false positives

Tags: perforce

When I run *Reconcile offline work* against certain directory subtree, two old untouched SQL files pop up as modified and I am offered to insert them into a changelist. But they are actually **unchanged** (I verified their binary images) and their File Type is correct (it is Unicode, file content is valid and they have [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning).

I tried this remedy which appeared logical to me:

1. revert them from the changelist (where they were added by *Reconcile offline work*)
2. remove them from the workspace (i.e. sync to rev. `#0`)

   - after this step, they were actually deleted from file system (verified)
   - after files were deleted from workspace, *Reconcile offline work* no longer reports them
3. get their latest revision again (with Force option enabled)

   - after this step, *Reconcile offline work* can find them again! – it should **not**

**How can I teach the Perforce there is nothing wrong with these files?**

(Can this be problem with the P4 database? Or with connection encoding? It is set to `UTF-8 (Unicode)` for all connections in P4V preferences.)

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on available information is that the server-side checksum does not match the file content (possibly because the file content on the server itself has been modified in some way since the checksum was computed -- this shouldn't happen).  Your admin can test this with the "p4 verify" command, and if desired update the checksum to match the new content with "p4 verify -v".

Comment: I have admin rights there and your answer makes perfect sense. So I tested the two files using `p4 verify` (no issues were reported) and then applied `p4 verify -v` to update their checksums. But exactly the same problem still persists. Perhaps I've found some bug in P4D, I don't know. (`P4D/NTX64/2012.2/607384 (2013/03/12)`) Perhaps I should upgrade the P4D?

Comment: Hm... well, since it wasn't the most likely thing, at this point pinning it down is going to require a little back-and-forth, which is discouraged on stackoverflow.  I'd suggest either contacting support or posting on the Perforce forums.  (Upgrading is never a bad idea, I'm just not positive it'll fix this particular issue without knowing what's causing it.)